# jQuery issue, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have this jQuery code. It pulls listings from the database that meet the amenity criteria. However, it breaks every other search feature on my page and I'm not sure why.

I get an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null` on line 185 which is this line...`if (amenityVal.length > 0) {`. I looked on SO for answers and tried `if(amenity && amenity.length > 0)`, and `if(amenity != null && amenity.length > 0`, and `if(amenity != null && != undefined && amenity.length > 0`.

When I do any of those, the other search features work, BUT the amenity search no longer does. Not sure where to go from here. Below is the jQuery.

```
// amenity
function filter() {
   var rows = $("tr.matrix-listing");
   rows.hide();

   var amenityVal = $("#select-amenities").val();
   if (amenityVal.length > 0) {
      var amenity = amenityVal;
      rows = rows.filter(function(i, v) {
         var rowAmenities = $(this).data("amenities").split(/\n/);
         return $(rowAmenities).filter(function(_, element) {
           return $.inArray(element.trim(), amenity) > -1;
         }).length === amenity.length;
       });
     }

 rows.show();
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <!-- Amenities -->
    <select multiple id="select-amenities" class="input-tags matrix-listing-filter" placeholder="Amenity">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="Central A/C">Central A/C</option>
      <option value="Doorman">Doorman</option>
      <option value="Duplex">Duplex</option>
      <option value="Elevator">Elevator</option>
      <option value="Laundry in building">Laundry in building</option>
      <option value="Dishwasher">Dishwasher</option>
      <option value="Common courtyard">Common courtyard</option>
      <option value="Private backyard">Private backyard</option>
      <option value="Shared backyard">Shared backyard</option>
      <option value="Balcony">Balcony</option>
      <option value="Terrace">Terrace</option>
      <option value="Patio">Patio</option>
      <option value="Roof access">Roof access</option>
      <option value="Private roof deck">Private roof deck</option>
      <option value="Storage space">Storage space</option>
      <option value="Bike storage">Bike storage</option>
      <option value="Gym">Gym</option>
      <option value="Private parking">Private parking</option>
      <option value="Washer dryer installed">Washer dryer installed</option>
      <option value="Washer dryer hookup">Washer dryer hookup</option>
      <option value="Wheelchair Accessible">Wheelchair Accessible</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please include the related HTML.

Comment: @Soviut I added the HTML.

Comment: You write: "I [...] tried `if(amenity && amenity.length > 0)`. Did you mean `amenityVal`?

Comment: @user2314737 Do you live in NYC, because I'd like to buy you a beer. I'm an idiot and I left out Val.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When trying out options I missed Val and just had amenity. Wondered why it didn't work. SMH. Below is the solution.

```
// amenity
var amenityVal = $("#select-amenities").val();
if (amenityVal != null && amenityVal != undefined && amenityVal.length > 0) {
   var amenity = amenityVal;
   rows = rows.filter(function(i, v) {
      var rowAmenities = $(this).data("amenities").split(/\n/);
      return $(rowAmenities).filter(function(_, element) {
         return $.inArray(element.trim(), amenity) > -1;
      }).length === amenity.length;
   });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Having to guess, because no HTML was provided in the question, but I think the DOM isn't ready when this script is run. Make sure you wrap your code in a "ready" callback. This will wait until the DOM has fully loaded, and your `#select-amenities` element exists, before running.

```
$(function() {
    // your code here...
});
```

Comment: That's probably the best guess that could be provided based on the limited info.